# clonezilla partition-backup

Tags: lubuntu, backup, clonezilla

I wonder if there´s anyone who can help me with a specific question.
I´m an avid user of clonezilla and I must say I´m really satisfied with it. Currently I´m using "clonezilla-live-20160210-wily-amd64".
Recently I had to play back a system-backup which I had created about 2 weeks earlier. That went alright.

Additionally:
As I have two partitions (/ and /home) I had backed up my current /home-partition first and thus as a second step I played back my /home partition afterwards.

I realized that when making a disk-backup clonezilla does that in 2 steps:
First my /-partition and
second my /home-partition.

My question now ist:
Does anyone know whether there´s a possibility of playing back only my /home-partition if need be provided that I´ve just a disk-backup available (which consists of / and /home-partition).

Thanks a lot in advance.
Rosika

P.S.:
system: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (64 bit)

Comment: When you say "play back", do you mean **restore**? Are you performing a disk **clone**, or a **partition** to image backup? It's also unclear about "2 steps" disk-backup. Cheers, Al

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. Of course I mean "restore". To clarify:

Comment: I was performing a disk clone to image backup. What I want to do is restore just the "/home"-partition out of that image backup (which consists of 1.) / and 2.) /home  - partitions.

Comment: You need to clarify more. I asked 3 questions. Disk **clone** has a problem restoring to smaller (even 1 block smaller) disks... which means that almost **ALL** clone restores will fail. Partition to image backups/restores should work fine. Cheers, Al

Comment: Disk clone copies more than just / and /home. It also copies diag partitions, boot partitions, etc. I believe that the answer to your question is... no, you can't restore just /home when you've done a complete disk to image backup. I could be wrong. Easy way to find out... go via the menus and see if there's an option to restore just partitions from a disk to image backup. But... why don't you check the FAQ at clonezilla.org? Cheers, Al

Comment: Well, it´s not a case of restoring my image to a smaller disk. I just want to restore it to the same disk if need be (just as a security measure). For example: If I have 2 DISK-backups (an old one and a younger one) is it possible to restore the root-partition ( / ) of the old one AND  (as a second step) the  /home  - partition of the younger one (in spite of the fact that I originally didn´t create partition-backups but  disk-backups? In other words: Is it possible to extract partition-backups out of a disk-backup?

Comment: Easy way to find out... go via the menus and see if there's an option to restore just partitions from a disk to image backup.

Comment: And, unless you've separated /home on it's own partition, it's included in /. Cheers, Al

Comment: O.K. my answer seems to have overlapped with yours. But that´s what I wanted to know. FAQ at clonezilla.org couldn´t give me the answer. I already looked there. Nevertheless. It seems the best I could do is create separate partition-backups for the root- and /home-partition. Thanks for your help. Rosika

Comment: O.K. that´s the way to go. BTW: I´ve separated /home, so I´ve got just two partitions. Thanks again. Rosika

Comment: I agree. I think partition to image backups would be the safest. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

You have the same feature in `Clonezilla` for restoring as you have for the backup.

**When you're backing up the choices are:**

- savedisk  - Save the whole disk
- saveparts  - Save partitions

**When you are restoring you have the same options:**

- restoredisk  - Restore the whole disk that was saved
- restoreparts  - Restire partitions from the disk that was saved

To restore a single partition just go into the `restoreparts` option and browse to where you saved your disk.  Then use the selector to pick the partition you want to restore.

As far as which partition has your root `/`, or your `/home`, you would have to know the partition number and can select that choice to restore.  During the restore process you will have the option of choosing where you want to restore it to.

**Restoring a full drive**

If you were going to restore the whole drive, you would choose the `restoredisk` instead of `restoreparts`.  Then you would proceed to select the drive you will be restoring the backed up drive to.

Comment: But... can the user perform a "disk to image" backup, and do a "specific partition only" restore? Cheers, Al

Comment: Yes.  The `save` or `restore` will go to whatever he choose as his `source` and `destination`.  If he choose `image` for save.  He would have to use that `image` for restore.   The `restore` will have to come from where it was `saved`... and the option to choose the source and destination is part of the `save` and `restore` process.

Comment: There's where the confusion is. If the user does an IMAGE backup of /dev/sda, can the user then restore ONLY /home? Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks a lot. That´s what I wanted to know. So it seems o.k. to make complete disk-backups. And I can choose which "/home"-partition I want to restore. That´s really convenient. Tnx for the help. Greetings.Rosika

Comment: @heynnema The confusion could be resolved by recognizing clonezilla doesn't show the names such as `home` or `root` for the partitions.  It shows` (as indicated in the answer) `sda1`, `sda2`, or `sdb1`, or `sdb2`, etc.  Those are the way the partitions are named.  The user will have to know if he placed `/home` in `sdb1` or `sda6`, by the name of the partition, in letters and numbers.

Comment: @Rosika Great! Glad to help.

Comment: I understand the sdax/sdbx part. The question, rephrased, is... the user does an entire disk to image backup, and his /home is on sda5, can the user go back later to that image, and only restore sda5? Or, does partition to image backups make more sense? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema As mentioned in the answer.  If he's going to choose a partition... thinking of `/home` might be what's causing the confusion.  We'll just call it `sda5`.  He select `restoreparts`, then proceed to where he wants to restore it to.  Then he proceeds to where he's going to restore it to.  If it's a device (a drive) then `Clonezilla` will give the list of partitions on the drive as part of the process.  He will then pick the partition on that `device` (drive) and proceed with the restore.

Comment: @Rosika, L. D. James says you can. Cheers, Al

Comment: Great help from both of you. I enjoyed the discussion and learned a lot. Tnx again.